# Is it possible to provide an active questions list that doesn't include closed questions?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I'd find it useful if there was an option to only display open questions. I find some of the closed questions useful but a click to open questions only (not unlike being able to click to bounty questions) would be useful.

Is there some way to do this that I've missed or is this a case of "that's just the way it is"?

I'm not asking on aesthetic grounds - it's purely a practical question - it's less efficient for me to scan a list of questions I can't answer than a list of questions I can answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

> closed:0

in the search which gives the url:

```
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3A0
```

See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search for more search options.

Comment: +1, the search page is full of juicy little options to make your life easier.